# TextMeshPro does not recognize subscripts and superscripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am replacing my current Text components with TextMeshPro, and when replacing texts containing characters such as superscripts and subscripts, I am getting the error.

I am aware that in TextMeshPro there is the option <sub> </sub> and <sup> </sup> to create superscripts and subscripts, but I preferred to do it directly with characters, as I did with normal Text.
The doubt comes from the fact that some characters are recognized, and others not:

² (recognized)
⁵ (recognized)
⁶ (not recognized)

The subscripts, on the other hand, do not recognize even one of them.

[image: 1]

Comment: I believe it would have to do with which glyphs your text atlas contains. The reason that the default Unity Text works is due to the text symbol existing. TextMeshPro has the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags to remove this issue completely by having both of them be handled by code instead of symbols. Is there any reason why you would need to just input the symbols directly? You can make shorthand for it or make constants to make it easier to embed them.

Comment: The reason is that I have a script that manages the translations, where I take an input string in a language and output the translated string. Handling the translation of strings directly with symbols instead of applying the code (<sup> and <sub>) made the translation script much more understandable, especially since I only use a simple x₁ or similar for superscripts and subscripts. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread contains all the information on solving the problem.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmeshpro-does-not-recognize-subscripts-and-superscripts.1151834/

In short words,
I changed the default font to a font that supported superscripts and subscripts. From that font I created two TMP fonts, one static with the main ASCII characters and one dynamic for the rest of the characters. Then I added the dynamic font in the static font fallbacks, and fine. Add the static font to the TMP and that's it.